# Find instance same text on different records, with different actions as a result

Tags: cobol

so my input file would be something like:

```
words words nothing important

words words nothing important

the quick brown fox 23

the quick brown fox 14

words words nothing important

words words nothing important
```

now, I'd like to be able to grab the 1st instance of "fox" and capture the "23" in WS-FIRST then grab the second instance of "fox" and capture "14" in WS-SECOND.

I'll be replacing "the quick brown fox" with a different string as well, but it's the same on both lines, so pretty easy.

The text is fixed in content and fixed in position and the number is also fixed in content, position and length.

Comment: Is your input in that fixed format, or can the data you are looking for be variably located?

Comment: No the input is fixed as far as positions go.. but the numbers *may* change.. which is why I need to pop the numbers into separate WS to use them later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem sounds like it would be well suited by a finite state machine or a simple parser.  This sounds like homework, so I won't write the code for you, but I'll offer some hints that might point you in the right direction.

- Process your input in a char by char loop, resist the urge to scan for words.
- Compare your input at that char to the longest literal first, so "quick brown fox" will hit before "fox".  This is called "greedy" scanning, and it is usually, but not always, the right way to go.
- Unless your search is case insensitive, you must case fold the input with function upper/lower-case
- When comparing to literals, place them first in the condion, this can make it easier to get a compiler error instead of a subtle bug in some cases and languages

So a main look might look like:

```
Perform Read-An-Input-Line
Perform until no-more-input

   Perform varying II from 1 by 1
     until II > length of Input-Line

     Evaluate true
       when 'the quick brown fox' = function lower-case( Input-Line (II:) )
          ...do replace for that string...

       when 'fox' = function lower-case( Input-Line (II:) )
          Move Input-Line (II + 5 : 2) to WS-Got-A-Number

     End-Evaluate

   End-Perform

   Perform Read-An-Input-Line
End-Perform
```

I hope some of that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. very well explained and I'll give that a shot for sure.. I'm curious as to why I'd resist the urge to scan for words? The input file is a parm that won't change, other than *possibly* the numbers.. To be more clear, "the quick brown fox" is actually a date, and the numbers are a minus from that date..

Comment: It'll never find `the quick brown fox`, you need to include the length of that text in the reference-modification in the test. It'll never find `fox` for the same reason. Having not taken false-hits into account, you need to bound the literals by space (and increase the length of the literals in the test). The search for fox also presumes no changing the input line. The loop termination also means you go "out of bounds" which could lead to failures or false hits.

Comment: No lenght needed on the reference mod, that is one of the reasons to put the literal first, the compile will compare up to the length of the first argument.  Anyway, it's very psuedo-code-y, I'm not doing homework unless I'm getting paid for it ;-)

Comment: The reason to resist the urge to scan for words is that it gets very complicated, very quickly.  Char by char scanning is much easier.  If you want a cool exercise, you could write a simple FSM parser that would let you scan for words, but you would find that you need to make it work at the char level.

Comment: hahah yah this isn't actual homework (do they even teach cobol anymore?) .. just trying to find a way to keep the input SQL file's ability to be quickly edited as far as the numerical values go rather than hard-coding them in.

Comment: What COBOL are you using? No COBOL I know will do that truncation. I think it would be non-standard.

Comment: Here's comparison of unequal length fields from the draft standard, and not marked as new in the standard ` Operands of unequal length. If the operands are of unequal length, comparison proceeds as though the shorter operand were extended on the right by sufficient alphanumeric spaces to make the operands of equal length.` Your COBOL is non-standard.

Comment: I'm using Enterprise Cobol, but I could well be thinking of another language, that is why testing and documentation are important.

Answer (score 1):

```
01  field-we-are-about-to-change.
    05  FILLER.
        10  the-bit-you-want-to-change PIC X(length of that text, you count).
            88  its-the-text-we-want VALUE ' the quick brown fox '.
        10  our-numeric-value PIC XX.
        10  FILLER PIC X(what is left of the input line).

01  WS-FIRST PIC XX.
01  WS-SECOND PIC XX.
01  FILLER PIC X VALUE "N".
    88  first-not-found VALUE "N".
    88  first-found VALUE "Y".

MOVE your-input TO field-we-are-about-to-change  

IF its-the-text-we-want 
    MOVE replacement-text TO the-bit-you-want-to-change
    IF first-not-found
        SET first-found TO TRUE
        MOVE our-numeric-value TO WS-FIRST
    ELSE
        MOVE our-numeric-value TO WS-SECOND
    END-IF
END-IF
```

If the input is fixed, just use definitions to treat it as fixed. Lots of variations possible.

Comment: ok yeah this makes perfect sense.. then just use the first found value in another IF statement to get the 2nd to WS-SECOND.. pefecto !!

Comment: @Jon I haven't used the value recovered from the first as a test. It is possible, if your data is reliable. If you set WS-FIRST to an initial value, there's always a risk that the field you pick up has that value. Whoops. Noticed a typo, editing...